# "Ways to prevent (a) Cold/Colds" Correct?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

Which of these are more proper and why?

> Ways to prevent a cold

or

> Ways to prevent colds

I learned in high school that "cold" is singular and plural and  at the time.

Comment: Both of these are acceptable. I'm not sure what you meant by your last sentence; in this case, the plural of cold is colds.

Comment: I'd suggest the definite article *the*, here as well as on your user page ("I am *the* owner of" or "a shareholder" or "one of the owners"), but not the indefinite article. You have to speak with conviction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Cold* as in the disease is a normal singular noun and requires *s* at the end if you are talking about more than one.

> Ways to prevent a cold *or* Ways to prevent colds

*Cold* also means "low temperature."  Nouns that refer to abstract attributes do not take articles.  If you see *cold* without an article, this meaning is likely intended.

> Ways to prevent cold

However, nouns that refer to types instead of concrete instances also do not take articles.  So it is possible to omit the article for *cold* if the word is being used to refer to a type of disease.

> Various diseases such as cold, flu, food poisoning are contagious.

Answer (score -1):

The Common Cold is a proper noun, as such it needs the definite article, nevertheless if "Common" is omitted. A quick search [doesn't agree though](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_cold).

The cold is at least a class of symptoms, so that [still needs the def. article](https://www.englishgrammar.org/definite-article/). The plural colds [seems possible](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/common-cold), but the colds sounds odd, there is just one class of these.